# ArcScene export to html

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcscene

I have 3D scene created from digital elevation model in ArcScene. I want to export it in a file and than open that file in any browser so I can view the 3D environment. I managed to do it in QGIS via threejs plugin which exported a bunch of files and one html file for viewing in a browser, but in ArcScene I cannot figure it out.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to import all of your layers into ArcGIS Online and recreate the scene there. A Scene through ArcGIS Online works very well and can be published easily to the public web. I have also tried to just export the scene to a 3D Web Scene which works well too. Here is the white paper ESRI has on it. [Exporting ArcScene Documents to 3D Web Scenes](http://support.esri.com/white-paper/2018)